# How does StackExchange.Redis store data in Redis in HashMap?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I want to understand how the StackExchange.Redis stores the data directly in the Redis. Can we pass the object as is or do we need to store every property separately? What is more efficient way to store the data - use StackExchange.Redis default way or converting into protobuf before storage?